# como retornar una variable con decimales en sql?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Tal vez sea algo de principiante pero no lo encuentro leyendo ni googleando.
Cuando hago `return` en una función me aparece como entero y necesito que devuelva decimal. Por ej.

```
DECLARE @gastos decimal(20,2)

SELECT @gastos=SUM(precio) 
FROM Vista_Boleteria_Gastos  
WHERE estado=0 AND id_boleteria=@Codigo

RETURN @gastos
```

Donde `SUM(precio)` es en total por ej: 1073.4
pero `return` segun lo que lei devuelve valores enteros
y efectivamente al probar la funcion me devuelve 1073
como hago para q me devuelva efectivamente 1073.4
saludos y gracias de antemano por cualquier ayuda

Comment: De que tipo es precio?

Comment: de tipo decimal

Comment: decimal de que tipo?

Comment: Lo estas haciendo en una funcion? si es asi, copiala por favor. si no es es asi, Cambia `RETURN` por `SELECT`

Answer (score 2):

Agradezco a todos los que comentaron ya encontré la solución

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[fun_bolgastos]
(@Codigo int)
RETURNS int  <<=== error 
RETURNs decimal(20,2) <<==correcto
```

hay que indicar que tipo va a retornar **RETURNS**

**esta es la funcion original**

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[fun_bolgastos]
(@Codigo int)
RETURNS INT <<==aca se indica como va a devolver la variable en este caso esta indicando q a la variable la devuelva como INT
AS
BEGIN
-- Declare the return variable here
DECLARE @gastos decimal(20,2)

-- consultar gastos
select @gastos=sum(precio) from Vista_Boleteria_Gastos  where estado=0 and id_boleteria=@Codigo

-- Retornar el valor escalar
RETURN @gastos <<=== y claro devuelve la variable sin decimales
END
```

**Esta es la funcion para q devuelva decimales**

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[fun_bolgastos]
(@Codigo int)
RETURNS decimal(20,2) <<==aca se indica como va a devolver la variable 
AS
BEGIN
    -- Declare the return variable here
    DECLARE @gastos decimal(20,2)
    -- consultar gastos
    select @gastos=sum(precio) from Vista_Boleteria_Gastos  where estado=0 and id_boleteria=@Codigo
    -- Retornar el valor escalar
    RETURN @gastos <<=== devuelve decimales
 END
```

Comment: Podes explicar un poco mas que hiciste? donde declaraste el tipo del return? como quedo tu funcion?

Comment: claro. esta es la funcion original

Comment: Y leiste el [tour]? o [ask]? o [answer]?.. Bienvenido, y gracias por el aporte...